# What is the identity of the person who gifted the Deathly Hallows to the three brothers?

Tags: harry-potter

> Detailed in here, is the story of the three brothers, who got the
>   Deathly Hallows, the Elder Wand, Resurrection Stone, and the Cloak of
>   Invisibility.

I wonder if the *Master of Death* (the one who granted the Deathly Hallows to three brothers) is an actual person or the personification of the Death itself?